# Implementing ladders in unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am trying to implement ladder climbing functionality in unity and i have achieved it to some degree.I have put circular collider on the top of the characters head so it detects when the ladder is above his head. what i want to do is that if i press the upward key it only climbs one step of the ladder and stays there..But instead the character falls as soon as i stop pressing the upward key and keeps going up if i press it one time..I have messed with the gravity of the rigidbody but no luck.

```
void Update()
{
    if((isgrounded  || !doublejump) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) )
    {
        anim.SetBool( "Ground",false);
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0,jumpforce));
        if(!doublejump && !isgrounded)
            doublejump = true;
    }
    if(Ladder && Input.GetAxis("Vertical")>0)
    {
        rigidbody2D.gravityScale =0;
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(rigidbody2D.velocity.x,Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*maxspeed);
    }
    if(!Ladder)
    {
        rigidbody2D.gravityScale =1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.any body wondering this was the answer.

```
void Update()
{
    if((isgrounded  || !doublejump) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) )
    {
        anim.SetBool( "Ground",false);
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0,jumpforce));
        if(!doublejump && !isgrounded)
            doublejump = true;
    }
    if(Ladder && Input.GetAxis("Vertical")>0)
    {

        anim.SetBool("LadderUp",true);
        transform.Translate (new Vector2(0,0.2f) * Time.deltaTime*maxspeed);
        rigidbody2D.gravityScale =0;
    //  rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(rigidbody2D.velocity.x,Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*maxspeed);
    }
    if(!Ladder)
    {
        anim.SetBool("LadderUp",false);
        rigidbody2D.gravityScale =1;
    }

}
```